# Counterintuitive phenomenon in a Poisson regression

Tags: generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression

I am trying to perform a simulation for Poisson regression.
I generated X1,X2 from $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, and then set $\lambda=0.5X1-0.3X2$. After that, I generated $Y$ from a Poisson distribution with $\lambda$ as its mean.

I generated 10000 samples, and want to fit the Poisson regression. I accidentally forgot to add the X1 in the model, meaning I only called:

```
glm(y ~ x2, family = poisson(link = "log"))
```

However, I find the estimate of the intercept is significant, which is not included in the model.
Here is the summary output of the model

```
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  0.121270   0.003038   39.92   <2e-16 ***
x2          -0.299331   0.002912 -102.79   <2e-16 ***
```

And I attach my source code here:

```
n <- 100000 
beta1 <- 0.5; beta2 <- -0.3 
x1 <- rnorm(n, 0, 1); x2 <- rnorm(n, 0, 1) 
lambda <- exp(beta1 * x1 + beta2 * x2) 
y <- rpois(n, lambda) 
fit <- glm(y ~ x2, family = poisson(link = "log"))
summary(fit)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data do not follow a Poisson distribution conditional on $X_2$, but only conditional on $X_1$ and $X_2$, so you can't expect valid tests.

More specifically, adding $\beta_1X_1$ to the linear predictor will multiply the fitted response by $\exp(\beta_1X_1)$, which has mean $\exp(0+\beta_1^2\times 1/2)=\exp(1/8)$. So the fitted intercept will be approximately 0.125=1/8 rather than zero.

Comment: Thanks so much for your insight. It is very clear. Appreciate it!